# Update drawRect using display() within an NSSliderCell?

Tags: swift

I have a drawRect display which plots a graph and I am attempting to change the parameters using a slider. In Objective-C I would use a slider action and include [self display] to update the display. This is the code in Swift which does nothing (the parameter is "freq"):

```
@IBAction func freqValue(sender: NSSliderCell) {
    freq = Float(sender.doubleValue)
    display()
}
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry!! I answered my own question - I should have made the slider continuous. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid calling `display` directly, both in Objective-C and in Swift. Instead, you should do

```
self.needsDisplay = true
```

This schedules drawing at the next runloop iteration. Calling `display` is only needed in some very rare special cases.